# ¿es posible acceder a mi aplicacion del localhost desde mi telefono android?

Tags: angular, xampp, localhost, error-403

Antes de hacer esta pregunta he leído e intentado todo lo que he encontrado pero nada me ha funcionado, lo único que me funcionó fue un programa llamado `ngrok`  pero se ejecuta muy lento, no se por que.

lo que estoy intentando ahora es conectando mi tlf vía usb, activo la ópción de anclaje usb, luego selecciono red domestica en windows, verifico la ip con ipconfig y luego intento acceder en el navegador de mi tlf con `ip/localhost`  o `ip/localhost:4002` pero me muestra un mensaje de "Acceso prohibido" con codigo 403. Mi aplicacion esta hecha con angular en el frontend corriendo en el pto 4002 y node.js en el backend corriendo en el pto 3000.

Según leí, el error de acceso prohibido se soluciona comentando o modificando unas líneas del archivo httpd.conf del XAMPP pero esas líneas que dicen que comente a mi no me aparecen, ya no se que mas intentar.

Estoy usando XAMPP

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar. Saludos!

Comment: lo que tiene que hacer es conectar tu celular a la misma red y correr tu aplicación, si ya tienes la ipv4 con ipconfig pues solo tienes que acceder por ejemplo 192.168.1.70:4200

Comment: Eso es lo que he hecho, pero como digo en mi pregunta, me muestra un mensaje que dice acceso prohibido, error 403.

Comment: Revisa los permisos que tienen en la carpeta y en caso de que tengas un htaccess también revisa si esta bien configurado,

Comment: ejecuté el comando que me dio la persona de la otra respuesta y ahora si se muestra en el teléfono pero el backend no me funciona y en la PC si. Alguna idea?

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, tienes problemas con el `backend` y con el `frontend`. Ambos problemas no parecen de programación sino de configuración de red. Por otro lado, tienes algo enredados algunos conceptos. El hecho de que Angular levante un servidor `webpack` en el equipo de desarrollo no significa que debas usar dicho servidor para conectarte desde otro equipo. Tienes XAMPP, por lo tanto lo ideal es realizar el despliegue (*deploy*) de tu aplicación en tu servidor, la puedes desplegar en modo desarrollo, y dejar que sea Apache el que sirva tu aplición.

Comment: Para que tu aplicación se conecte con el `backend`, podrías configurar un [servidor proxy inverso](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), de forma que toda solicitud a alguna ruta de tu servidor, sea redirigida a tu aplicación NodeJS. Por ejemplo, puedo establecer que toda solicitud (realizada por tu `frontend`) a la ruta `localhost/api` sea redirigida hacia `localhost:3000`. Esto es totalmente transparente para el cliente. La redirección de puerto la hace Apache, mediante la configuración de dicho proxy inverso.

Comment: Si tienes otras dudas, te invito a pasar por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) de SOes y con gusto te las puedo aclarar. Saludos

Comment: Abundando un poco en lo que te comenta @MauricioContreras, en la pregunta no queda muy claro qué tipo de uso quieres dar a esa conexión entre el servidor y el cliente (la App Android). Si lo que te interesa es comunicar datos entre servidor y cliente lo que se suele hacer es programar un WebService o una API (en el servidor) y ofrecerla mediante una URL. Del lado de Android programarías una petición dirigida a esa URL. Es relativamente simple hacer esto con herramientas como `Volley`. Si en un futuro los datos tienen que ser ofrecidos a todo el mundo, sólo cambiaría la URL, nada más.

Comment: Tengo una página web realizada con Angular y el backend está hecho con node.js, simplemente lo que quiero es poder probarla desde mi teléfono, básicamente quería era ver cómo se comportaba el responsive (se que hay plugins en el navegador para probar el responsive pero quería hacerlo directamente desde el tlf). La solución que me dió Samir me funcionó en parte (se carga el front) pero intenté ingresar con el login y no hace nada, cabe destacar que desde la PC ingreso con la IP que aparece en Ipconfig y si funciona sin problemas. Disculpa si no me explique bien en mi pregunta.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a querer pasar por una App Android para probar el *responsive*. Es incluso contradictorio, *responsive* significa que te web se vería de forma adecuada desde cualquier dispositivo (PC, móvil, tablet, etc), pero **accediendo a ella por navegador**. Cuando programas una App en base a una web pasamos a otro nivel, generalmente obtienes la información de la web, pero la presentas de un modo más propio de una App. Por poner un ejemplo, si en la web tienes un Menú tipo hamburguesa basado en frameworks como Bootstrap, en la App usarás Navigation View para ese menú.

Comment: Creo que aún no me he explicado bien amigo. Lo que en realidad estoy intentando es acceder a la página web desde el navegador Chrome móvil (desde el teléfono), no intento hacer una aplicación, simplemente quería ver cómo se mostraba mi página cuándo se accede desde el navegador del tlf, ver cómo se adaptaba a la pantalla móvil probandola directamente desde el tlf sin usar los plugins del navegador en la PC. .

Comment: me paso lo mismo solo deshabilite el firewall de windows y funciono pero con un problema solo accede al frontend no me carga la informacion, no sabras como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En caso de querer hacer testing con google chrome desde el mobil puedes usar:
" chrome://inspect/#devices "
conectando el dispositivo con un cable USB al ordenador, en port forwarding permite introducir la dirección utilizada y solo nesecitas colocar esta en el input del browser del android, suerte :)
(edit): ambos tienen que permanecer conectados pues estas compilando desde el ordenador y lo que hace google es leerla, ver más: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?utm_campaign=2016q3&utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=dcc#reverse-port-forwarding

Comment: estoy fue lo que me funcionó, en la opción "port forwarding" agregué tanto el puerto 4200 (Angular) como el puerto 3000 (node.js) y me funciona tanto el front como en el back desde mi tlf android. Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Lo q yo hago es correr el proyecto con

> ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Con esta deberia ser suficiente, solo queda con que accedas a la ip local del computador y puerto desde tu celular algo como `198.156.0.14:4200`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, lo corrí con ese comando y ahora si pude acceder. como se hace con el backend? como menciono en mi pregunta, el backend está hecho con node.js y corre en el puerto 3000, mi aplicacion tiene un login y si ejecuto ``` http://192.168.42.194:4200/entry ``` en la pc si me hace las peticiones al backend y todo funciona normal, pero si hago lo mismo desde el tlf no me funciona, no hace nada. Sabes que hacer en ese caso ?

Comment: no estoy seguro, pero debería poner un segundo parámetro a listen quedaria algo como: app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0'); El servidor se ejecutará en todas las interfaces disponibles. Si esto llega a funcionar, el front deberia apuntar al equipo nuevamente, con el puerto correspondiente al backend

Comment: Lo hice pero sigue sin funcionar. tu has probado tus aplicaciones con backend desde el tlf ?

Comment: Lo logre una vez, pero no recuerdo el comando. tocara q uses ngrok para el back mientras, si algo actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Con ngrok tampoco me funciona el backend desde el tlf.

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que en tu frontend apuntes tu endpoint a la ip de tu PC. Por ejemplo si tú ip es 192.168.1.33 podrías reemplazarlo algo así. Antes http://localhost:3000 ahora http://192.168.1.33:3000